# Web Audio API Note On

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I am attempting to build an interface that allows timing / rhythm (potentially pitch) input to a Web Audio Oscillator node. in effect creating a 'step sequencer'.

What's the best way to trigger scheduled NoteOn for the Web Audio API Oscillator Nodes?

In a specific pattern, i.e. 1/4 notes, 1/8th notes or a user entered pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is it a question of how a step sequencer normally works, or is it a question of how you'd implement this "normal" behaviour in Web Audio?

Comment: To Clarify - Question of how I would implement this "normal" behaviour in Web Audio.
I am familiar with sequencers + synthesizers in the audio domain. Looking for the best way to approach this using Web Audio API + Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question, and in fact I just published an HTML5Rocks article on this very topic: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was after.